# Implementation of Doubly Linked List with sentinel in C++ trying to replicate the stl std::list

Tags: c++, linked-list, reinventing-the-wheel, c++17, collections

I am currently trying to replicate the STL `std::list` interface with my own list implementation (doubly linked list with sentinel) to learn about all the advanced topics (like iterators, allocators, ...). Before I add the methods  from the "operations" section in the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/), I'd love to hear your thoughts and feedback to what I've got so far.

```
#ifndef DOUBLY_LINKED_LIST_HH
#define DOUBLY_LINKED_LIST_HH

#include <stdexcept>        // exceptions
#include <type_traits>      // remove_cv
#include <utility>          // swap
#include <cstddef>          // ptrdiff_t
#include <cassert>          // assert
#include <initializer_list> // initializer_list
#include <memory>           // allocator_traits

template<typename T, typename _Alloc = std::allocator<T>>
class list 
{

private:
    #pragma region Node
    struct Node
    {
        Node(Node* prev, Node* next) : prev(prev), next(next) { }
        Node(Node* prev, Node* next, const T& data) : prev(prev), next(next), data(data) { }
        Node(Node* prev, Node* next, T&& data) : prev(prev), next(next), data(std::move(data)) { }
        T data;
        Node* prev;
        Node* next;
    };
    #pragma endregion

    #pragma region Iterator
    template<typename R>
    struct Iterator
    {
        Node* current;
        Iterator(Node* node) : current(node) { }
        Iterator(const list& list, size_t index = 0) : current(list.sentinel->next) { operator+(index); };
        bool operator==(Iterator const& other) const { return current == other.current; }
        bool operator!=(Iterator const& other) const { return !(*this == other); }

        Iterator& operator++() { current = current->next; return *this; }
        Iterator& operator--() { current = current->prev; return *this; }
        Iterator& operator++(int) { Iterator result(*this); ++(*this); return result; }
        Iterator operator--(int) { Iterator result(*this); --(*this); return result; }
        Iterator& operator+(size_t offset)
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < offset; ++i) 
                operator++();
            return *this;
        }
        Iterator& operator-(size_t offset)
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < offset; ++i) 
                operator--();
            return *this;
        }

        R& operator*() const { return current->data; }
        R* operator->() const { return &(current->data); }
    };
    #pragma endregion

    Node* sentinel;
    size_t element_count;
public:
    using allocator_type = _Alloc;

    using value_type = T;
    using reference = typename _Alloc::reference;
    using const_reference = typename _Alloc::const_reference;
    using pointer = typename _Alloc::pointer;
    using const_pointer = typename _Alloc::const_pointer;
    using size_type = size_t;
    using difference_type = ptrdiff_t;

    using iterator = Iterator<T>;
    using const_iterator = Iterator<const T>;
    using reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<iterator>;
    using const_reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator>;

    #pragma region Big Five

    list()
    {
        sentinel = new Node(nullptr, nullptr);
        sentinel->next = sentinel;
        sentinel->prev = sentinel;
    }
    ~list()
    {
        clear();
        delete sentinel;
    }

    list(list&& other) noexcept // move constructor
    {
        other.swap(*this);
    }
    list(const list& other) // copy constructor
    {
        for (auto const& val : other) 
        {
            push_back(val);
        }
    }
    list& operator=(const list& other) // copy assignment
    {
        return *this = list(other);
    }
    list& operator=(list&& other) noexcept // move assignment
    {
        other.swap(*this);
        return *this;
    }

    #pragma endregion

    #pragma region Modifiers

    void swap(list& other) noexcept 
    {
        std::swap(sentinel->next->prev, other.sentinel->next->prev);
        std::swap(sentinel->prev->next, other.sentinel->prev->next);
        std::swap(sentinel->next, other.sentinel->next);
        std::swap(sentinel->prev, other.sentinel->prev);
        std::swap(element_count, other.element_count);
    }

    void push_back(const T& value)
    {
        Node* n = new Node(sentinel->prev, sentinel, value);
        sentinel->prev->next = n;
        sentinel->prev = n;
        ++element_count;
    }

    void push_back(T&& value) 
    {
        Node* n = new Node(sentinel->prev, sentinel, std::move(value));
        sentinel->prev->next = n;
        sentinel->prev = n;
        ++element_count;
    }

    void push_back() 
    {
        Node* n = new Node(sentinel->prev, sentinel);
        sentinel->prev->next = n;
        sentinel->prev = n;
        ++element_count;
    }

    void push_front(const T& value)
    {
        Node* n = new Node(sentinel, sentinel->next, value);
        sentinel->next->prev = n;
        sentinel->next = n;
        ++element_count;
    }
    void push_front(T&& value)
    {
        Node* n = new Node(sentinel, sentinel->next, std::move(value));
        sentinel->next->prev = n;
        sentinel->next = n;
        ++element_count;
    }

    void pop_back() 
    {
        // No exception according to specification: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/container.requirements.general#10
        Node* tmp = sentinel->prev;
        sentinel->prev = sentinel->prev->prev;
        sentinel->prev->next = sentinel;
        delete tmp;
        --element_count;
    }
    void pop_front()
    {
        Node* tmp = sentinel->next;
        sentinel->next = sentinel->next->next;
        sentinel->next->prev = sentinel;
        delete tmp;
        --element_count;
    }

    void clear() 
    {
        Node* next;
        for (Node* n = sentinel->next; n != sentinel; n = next)
        {
            next = n->next;
            delete n;
        }
        sentinel->next = sentinel;
        sentinel->prev = sentinel;
        element_count = 0;
    }
    
    template<class InputIterator>
    void assign(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
    {
        clear();
        for (InputIterator it = first; it != last; ++it)
        {
            push_back(*it);
        }
    }
    void assign(size_type n, const value_type& val)
    {
        clear();
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            push_back(val);
        }        
    }
    void assign (std::initializer_list<value_type> list)
    {
        clear();
        for (const value_type& i : list) {
            push_back(i);
        }
    }

    template<class... Args>
    void emplace(const_iterator position, Args&&... args)
    {
        Node* node = new Node(position.current->prev, position.current);
        allocator_type alloc;
        std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::construct(alloc, &(node->data), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        position.current->prev->next = node;
        position.current->prev = node;
    }
    template <class... Args>
    void emplace_front (Args&&... args)
    {
        emplace(cbegin(), args...);
    }
    template<class... Args>
    void emplace_back(Args&&... args)
    {
        emplace(cend(), args...);
    }

    template <class InputIterator>
    iterator insert (const_iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
    {
        iterator result;
        Node* prev = position.current->prev;
        Node* current = nullptr;

        size_t count = 0;
        for (InputIterator it = first; it != last; ++it)
        {
            current = new Node(prev, nullptr, *it);
            if (it == first) 
                result = iterator(current);
            prev->next = current;
            prev = current;
            ++element_count;
        }
        if (current != nullptr) 
            current->next = position;
        return result;
    }
    iterator insert(const_iterator position, size_type n, const value_type& val)
    {
        insert(position, {val, n});
    }
    iterator insert(const_iterator position, std::initializer_list<value_type> il) 
    {
        insert(position, il.begin(), il.end());
    }
    iterator insert(const_iterator position, const value_type& val)
    {
        insert(position, {val});
    }
    void resize(size_type n)
    {
        resize(n, T{});
    }
    void resize (size_type n, const value_type& val)
    {
        if (size() < n)
        {
            iterator first = begin() += n-1;
            erase(first, end());
        }
        else if (size() > n)
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < size() - n; ++i) 
            {
                push_back(val);
            }
        }
    }

    iterator erase(const_iterator position)
    {
        erase(position, const_iterator(position.current->next));
    }
    iterator erase(const_iterator first, const_iterator last)
    {
        iterator result = iterator(last.current->next);

        Node* current = first.current;
        while (current != last.current) 
        {
            Node* tmp = current;
            current = current->next;
            delete tmp;
            --element_count;
        }
        
        return result;
    }

    #pragma endregion

    #pragma region Element access
    
    reference front() { return sentinel->next->data; }
    const_reference front() const { return sentinel->next->data; }

    reference back() { return sentinel->prev->data; }
    const_reference back() const { return sentinel->prev->data; }

    reference operator[](size_t index) { return *(iterator(*this, index)); }
    const_reference operator[](size_t index) const { *this[index]; }
    
    reference at(size_t index)
    {
        if (index >= size()) throw throw std::out_of_range("index out of bounds");
        return *this[index];
    }
    const_reference at(size_t index) const
    {
        return at(index);
    }

    #pragma endregion

    #pragma region Capacity
    size_t size() const { return element_count; }

    bool empty() const { return size() == 0; }
    #pragma endregion

    #pragma region Iterators
    iterator begin() { return iterator(sentinel->next); }
    iterator end() { return iterator(sentinel); }
    const_iterator begin() const { return const_iterator(sentinel->next); }
    const_iterator end() const { return const_iterator(sentinel); }
    const_iterator cbegin() const { return const_iterator(sentinel->next); }
    const_iterator cend() const { return const_iterator(sentinel); }

    reverse_iterator rbegin() { return reverse_iterator(end); }
    reverse_iterator rend() { return reverse_iterator(begin()); }
    const_reverse_iterator crbegin() const { return const_reverse_iterator(end()); }
    const_reverse_iterator crend() const { return const_reverse_iterator(begin()); }
    #pragma endregion

};

#endif // !DOUBLY_LINKED_LIST_HH
```

Comment: I'm finding numerous little errors in this, including an apparent compilation error in `resize`.  How extensively have you tested this?

Comment: Fix all the compilation errors, test your code and fix the obvious logical errors, then come back and [edit] the corrected code into the question.  As it stands the code is not working and not in a reviewable state.  See [ask].

Comment: Currently does not compile.

Comment: Compiler errors here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/7yK3xWyGCLoX7idE